# Unsupported engine error when upgrading node

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules, next.js13, react-fullstack

When I try to update Node to latest version, this error is coming

```
npm ERR! code EBADENGINE
npm ERR! engine Unsupported engine
npm ERR! engine Not compatible with your version of node/npm: npm@10.1.0
npm ERR! notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: npm@10.1.0
npm ERR! notsup Required: {"node":"^18.17.0 || >=20.5.0"}
npm ERR! notsup Actual:   {"npm":"9.7.1","node":"v16.17.0"}
```

I have tried

```
npm install -g npm@latest
npm install -g n
```

Same result

Comment: I'd suggest to use [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) for managing node.js versions